# Layer stacking images in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to layer stack two Landsat images from the dry season and the wet season.

Is the function 'composite' in earth engine going to give me the layer stacking?

Comment: By Earth Engine do you mean Google Earth Engine or something else?

Comment: in EarthEngine terminology a 'composite' is a single image. What you are looking for is either an 'Image Collection' or a 'Image' with multiple bands. What you use is solely dependent on what you plan to do with your image stack. I suggest you have a look into the [official EarthEngine documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/) since this and all of your previous questions are answered in there.

Comment: Thanks Kersten. I have been reading the official Earth Engine documentation and its not very clear about Layerstacking as I understand it from ENVI or any other proprietary Image analysis software.

Answer (score 10):

The [ee.Image.addBands()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageaddbands) method can be used to "stack" bands from two Landsat images. For example:

```js
var wet = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T/LC80440342017005LGN00');
var dry = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T/LC80440342016195LGN00');
var stacked_composite = wet.addBands(dry);
print('stacked_composite bands', stacked_composite.bandNames());
```

Note that the resulting image object **stacked_composite** will retain the metadata of the primary image (**wet**). You may also want to rename the bands with [ee.Image.rename()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagerename) either before or after stacking them.