# Exporting large number of images from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

In my analysis on Google Earth Engine, I want to export a large number of image files to drive. In general, for this, we can use a for loop to loop through the images and export them with `Export.image.toDrive` method.

```
  Export.table.toDrive(image_ndvi, 'ndvi', 'LST Paper/Indiecs');
```

But this method put those images in the Task Manager (Tasks tab) and we have to manually click run two times for each image. I have around 145 single-band remote sensing indices and surface temperature images of the same area, so this process is not very efficient for me.

I have done all the analysis in GEE and want to export the output images so that I can create maps for my report.

How do I export these many images at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one batch tool https://github.com/gee-hydro/gee_monkey, but it did not work very well for me. Or consider stacking all the images into one following the instructions at [Layer stacking images in Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228445/layer-stacking-images-in-earth-engine) using a loop, and exporting just that one image.

```
var imgList = aImgCollection.toList(aImgCollection.size());

var id = 0;

var firstImage = ee.Image( imgList.get(id) );

// these two lines use the image ID to rename each band to make sure they are different
var filename = ee.String("rename_").cat(firstImage.id().getInfo()).getInfo();
firstImage = firstImage.rename(filename);
id = id + 1;

while (id < aImgCollection.size().getInfo()){
  var aImage = ee.Image( imgList.get(id) );

  // these two lines use the image ID to rename each band to make sure they are different
  filename = ee.String("rename_").cat(aImage.id().getInfo()).getInfo();
  aImage = aImage.rename(filename);

  firstImage = firstImage.addBands(aImage); 
  
  id = id + 1;
}
```

Comment: With this method, I'm able to export the bands at once, but the bands don't retain their original names even after doing `.rename(filename)`. How to solve this?

Comment: @Badal actually the rename is meant to change the original names, so the same band from different files are not confused with each other in the new file. If you do not want this just don't do this line.

Comment: But in the exported output file, the name of different bands are band1, band2, and so on.  It is not showing the original band names. Why?

Comment: @Badal I was able to reproduce your error when I exported a few hundred bands, but not if I only exported, e.g., 2 bands. Can you try exporting just a few bands? Perhaps this is an issue with GEE.

Comment: It's not working for me. [This code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8ef151064a229a1ab1ee7f2a2ff56ec1) is exporting 3 bands. But the names are "band_1", "band_2", and "band_3". Is there something wrong here?

Comment: @Badal I ran the code, exported the file to my google drive, and opened the file using ArcGIS. It shows the correct band names for me...

Comment: That's odd. It is not happening in my case. However, the original intent of this question has been answered. So I am accepting the answer. I have posted [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415186/keeping-the-actual-band-names-in-gee-exported-images) for the problem at hand. Please check.