# Keeping the actual band names in GEE exported images

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am exporting some images from Google Earth Engine. But in the exported image the band names are not there. Means it is showing band_1, band_2, and so on instead of their actual band names.

[This](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8ef151064a229a1ab1ee7f2a2ff56ec1) is my GEE code. The image which I'm trying to export has the following bands,

[image]

The code snippet for exporting selected bands is,

```
var selectedImage = image.select(['ST_B6', 'ndvi', 'ndbi'])

Export.image.toDrive({
      image: selectedImage,
      description: 'testRun2',
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1000000000000,
      region: mumbai
    });
```

In ArcMap, the exported image shows band names as,

[image]

**How do I keep the actual band names in the exported image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to set the band names in a geotiff.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help Badal, but maybe a later user will find this helpful.

I'm definitely not arguing with Noel. But you can kind of work around the problem.

If you take your Image and cast to an Image Collection, you can then change all of the images in the collection to bands. The bands can have different names. The only problem is that using `toBands` prepends the Image Collection name to the band names. I haven't figured out how to rename them inside the cast to something shorter, but the export will keep the bands names printed in the console. They're long, but you can probably edit them pretty simply to something shorter in the ArcGIS.

In other words, generically:

```
var imageselection = image.select(bands_you_want);
var export = ee.ImageCollection(imageselection).toBands();

Export.image.toDrive(export...)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/54fdcb8be4423487a1465815eb6af544

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe this can help. However, I have tried to export the image as per the code mentioned in the original question, and now the band names are there in the exported image. I think they have added the feature to retain the band names. Please note that I may be wrong as I have not tested this many time.

Comment: You're welcome. It's good to know that your original code works the way you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

even though I have faced the same issues but somehow I figured it out through QGIS. once you export the image collection from GEE open it in QGIS go to properties> information there you can find the band names.
[image: Here in gee I exported image collection wheat23laibands]

[image: When I open the same image collection in arcgis their bands doesn't have any names.]
[image: But I can identify band names here in QGIS]