# Renaming band names with GeoTIFF in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1

I am trying to rename the band names of my raster stack in GEE. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var start_date = ee.Date('2020-11-01');
var finish_date = ee.Date('2020-12-01');
var orbit = 'DESCENDING';

var collectionS1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', orbit))
    .filterDate(start_date, finish_date)
    .filterBounds(polygons);

 // Get the VV collection.
var band_names = ['S1_VV_11'];
var collectionVV = collectionS1.select('VV').select (band_names);
// Get the VH collection.
var band_names1 = ['S1_VH_11'];
var collectionVH = collectionS1.select('VH').select(band_names1);


var VV = ee.Image(collectionVV.first().clip(polygons));  //roi_A is my rectangular roi
var VH = ee.Image(collectionVH.first()); 

// I would like to take VV and VH and stack them and download
var VVVH = VV.addBands(VH)

print(VVVH)

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: VVVH,
  description: 'S1_2020_11',
  scale: 10,
  region: polygons,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  //formatOptions: {
  //  cloudOptimized: true
  //}
});
```

But it throws me an error like this:

```
Image (Error)
Collection.first: Error in map(ID=null):
Image.select: Pattern 'S1_VH_11' did not match any bands
```

Is it possible to rename the band or keep the original band names instead of output like Band 1, Band 2, etc... Or do I need to change the output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rename all the images inside your image collection, you need to use the `map` function. This way you can rename each image with the new names. Additionally, if you look in the Docs section of GEE, you'll notice that `ee.ImageCollection` objects do not have a `rename` method and its `select` method does not have an option to rename directly the bands with a second list.

```
// Get the VV collection.
var band_names = ['S1_VV_11'];
var collectionVV = collectionS1.select('VV')
                               .map(function(image){
                                 return ee.Image(image).rename(band_names);
                               });
// Get the VH collection.
var band_names1 = ['S1_VH_11'];
var collectionVH = collectionS1.select('VH')
                               .map(function(image){
                                  return ee.Image(image).rename(band_names1);
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel 1 images are not called 'S1_VV_11' and 'S1_VH_11' as you seem to suggest in your code. Additionally there is currently no way to set names to bands in a geotiff (export): [Keeping the actual band names in GEE exported images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415186/keeping-the-actual-band-names-in-gee-exported-images)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/689f0b4a874904d9ad0b7cd314ed18c0

Answer (score 0):

To rename the bands, you have to use .rename()

```
    var collectionVV = collectionS1.select('VV').rename ('S1_VV_11');
```